# How to set up Ubuntu Display higher resolution with Guest addition CD image in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, resolution

How to set up Ubuntu Display higher resolution with Guest addition CD image in VirtualBox

I get error `Vboxclient: failed to register resizing support, rc=VERR INVALID FUNCTION`

This problem is on 20.04.2 so 64-bit. However, resolutions work on 18.04.5 32-bit without Guest addition CD image.

[image: vboxclient failed to register resizing support rc=verr invalid function]

Comment: I have Ubuntu 20.04 in a different virtual app. When I click on the desktop and select display, I see resolution settings from 2560x1600 down to 1400x1050.  Can you do this? and what do you see? or just the error above?  What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @John what other virtual app you use? This problem is on 20.04.2 so 64-bit. However, resolutions work on 18.04.5 32-bit without Guest addition CD image.

Comment: I use VMware Workstation V16. While I have used VMware since V1, problems in here with VBOX prevent me from ever switching.